# Caret: Get all models instead of only the finalModel

Tags: r, r-caret, caret

For subsequent analysis I want have all the model for each fold, not only the finalModel.
Is this possible?

```
  fitControl <- trainControl(
method = "repeatedcv",
number = 3,
verboseIter = FALSE,
savePredictions = TRUE,
returnData=TRUE)





dat=data.frame(y=as.factor(rbinom(1000, 1, prob=0.5)),
                 x=rnorm(1000,10,1))
        

levels(dat$y) <- c("A","P")
  
  cv_caret<-train(y~.,data=dat,method="glm",family=binomial,trControl=fitControl)
```

Comment: You are only using one model, `glm(y~., dat, family = binomial)`, just fitted on multiple folds. Nothing in the model changes.

Comment: Hmm. seem you are right. Maybe I mean all the formula's (coefficients and intercepts) for each fold

Comment: caret doesn't store these. tidymodels neither as far as I can see. `h2o` does store the cv models and all the used coefficients and intercepts.